# Multiple checks on one field in phpMyAdmin (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, field, constraints

I'm creating a table with MySQL in phpMyAdmin. I want to use a CHECK constraint to ensure that new values for VATPERCENTAGE are between 0 and 100. The current syntax is incorrect. How can I use both CHECKs correctly, or better yet can I use a single CHECK to see if it's between the two numbers?

```
CREATE TABLE JOBSFORCLIENTS(
 JOBID               NUMERIC(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 CLIENTID            NUMERIC(3) NOT NULL,
 VATPERCENTAGE       NUMERIC(3,2) NOT NULL CHECK (VATPERCENTAGE >= 0) AND CHECK (VATPERCENTAGE <= 100)
 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL still **doesn't support** CHECK constraints.

> **[CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)**
>   The CHECK clause is parsed but **ignored** by all storage engines.

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47326/1)** demo

---

Now you can enforce this constraint with a pair of triggers though

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER VATPERCENTAGE_CHECK_INSERT 
BEFORE INSERT ON JOBSFORCLIENTS
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.VATPERCENTAGE = IF(NEW.VATPERCENTAGE BETWEEN 0 AND 100, NEW.VATPERCENTAGE, NULL);

CREATE TRIGGER VATPERCENTAGE_CHECK_UPDATE 
BEFORE UPDATE ON JOBSFORCLIENTS
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.VATPERCENTAGE = IF(NEW.VATPERCENTAGE BETWEEN 0 AND 100, NEW.VATPERCENTAGE, NULL);
```

*The idea is simple - if a new value is out of scope of valid values we simply violate `NOT NULL` constraint on `VATPERCENTAGE` column effectively preventing a row from being inserted and (or) updated. This approach will work on MySQL prior to 5.5. If you want to output an appropriate message you can use [`SIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) if you're on MySQL 5.5 or up.*

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a889/1)** demo

Answer (score -1):

Really simple fix actually.

```
CHECK (VATPERCENTAGE BETWEEN 0 AND 100)
```

Comment: For the sake of further readers this is a **wrong answer**. MySQL **ignores** `CHECK` constraints. See a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47326/1) demo.